# How to fix "Import Pandas inside 'Ipython' and 'Jupyter Notebook' fails on windows"

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

**I have pandas installed** on my system but it won't work and send an error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' inside ipython.

Error message I get when I try to import pandas inside ipython:

```
    In [1]: import pandas
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-38d4b0363d82> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Error message I get when I tried to import pandas in jupyter notebook:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

-
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-38d4b0363d82> in <module>
----> 1 import pandas

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py in <module>
      9 for dependency in hard_dependencies:
     10     try:
---> 11         __import__(dependency)
     12     except ImportError as e:
     13         missing_dependencies.append("{0}: {1}".format(dependency, str(e)))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
    138 
    139     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 140     from . import _distributor_init
    141 
    142     from . import core

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
     24                 # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
     25                 # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
---> 26                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     27                 DLL_filenames.append(filename)
     28     if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    354 
    355         if handle is None:
--> 356             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    357         else:
    358             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling pandas but no luck

Comment: What do you mean by “I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling pandas but no luck“. You can’t install or you get a message that it is already installed?

Comment: it says Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\\users...\lib\site-packages

Comment: Thinking out loud. What is the name of the file? By any chance is it named 'pandas'? If yes, change it.

Answer (score 2):

In your iPython Notebook, can you try running the following?

```
!pip install pandas
```

And then restart your iPython Notebook kernel?

It's mostly likely you've installed pandas to a different virtual env.

Comment: It shows following output:

Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (0.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python37\site-packages (from pandas) 
....

Comment: I would suggest you uninstall your python and then reinstall using the anaconda distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted using a different interpreter to run the code, such as Visual Studio Code, or running from the terminal, sometimes interpreters may not have the same directory for modules as where they are being installed to using pip.

Comment: I reinstalled python using the anaconda distribution.
**Problem Fixed**